# How to get the text from h1 element?

Tags: asp.net

I have a master and content page:

1) On master page:

Markup:

```
<h1 id="SeoActionH1" runat="server"></h1>
```

Code behind:

```
public string SeoActionHeader1
{
    set
    {
        SeoActionH1.InnerText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value;
    }
    get
    {
        return SeoActionH1.InnerText;
    }
}
```

2) On content page:

Code behind:

```
private Main MainMasterPage
{
    get { return Master as Main; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string groupName = MainMasterPage.SeoActionHeader1;
    }
}
```

If for example the content of h1 is: Hello, I've got the following:

```
"\r\n                                "
```

What's going on?

Comment: where are you setting values in `h1`?

Comment: It was set earlier from database.

Comment: put that code in the question. Where you are setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

did you call this `SeoActionHeader1` property on page load event?

or ty this way

```
public string MyString{ get; set; }

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value;
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<h1><%= MyString %></h1>
```